# How can I get Canadian Skype Access, and using Skype

Tags: skype, voip

I live in Canada and am having trouble understanding how to use Skype.

1. Can I get an unused phone number or do I need to have a phone number which I can then assigh to Skype. What do I need to do to achieve this?
2. I know I need to have my computer on, but will an incoming call wake my computer up from hibernation or does it have to be active?
3. How will I receive a "ring" if I am using another program and some one wants to reach me?
4. I cannot seem to find out what services are included in the monthly subscription:

   - IS there call waiting?
   - Is there voice mail?

I appreciate any direction. Best regards.

Comment: For #2 you could bye a Skype Phone (no computer needed) http://www.skype.com/intl/en/allfeatures/cordlessphones/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Skype will give you a number.
2. I wouldn't think your computer would wake up in time for a call.
3. Most modern operating systems can playback multiple audio streams from multiple programs.
4. Here is the skype pricing page:  http://www.skype.com/prices/

Everything looks to be a la carte - no set plans, which is nice.

Comment: AS far as I can tell, I canot get a number from Skype which will allow people tp phone me from their land or cell phones. Does anyone know if this is true, or am I misinformed?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can find out, Skype is unable to give me a number that people can contact me on.
Therefor it is useless to me.